# How do you turn tuples(keys of dict) with integers into a list of str

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

While I was writing some code, I got stuck on the part where we have to convert a tuple key from a dictionary to a list of strings.

```
dict = {(3,4):45, (4,5):6, (5,6):45}
```

then get the keys from dict and turn them into a list of strings like

```
['3,4', '4,5', '5,6']
```

how would you approach this function.?
I tried to use the for loops, but it didn't work.

```
for i in dict:
    lista = ','
    for x in i:
        lista.join(str(x))
        
return list(lista)
```

Answer (score 3):

First, don't overwrite python builtins. Use a meaninful variable name. For instance `data`.

```
data = {(3,4):45, (4,5):6, (5,6):45}
```

Second `str.join` returns the joined string. It doesn't perform it inplace especially since strings are immutable. Also it only works on strings so you will need to turn the `int`s to `str`. Try the following list comprehension:

```
result = [','.join(map(str, key)) for key in data]
```

Result:

```
['3,4', '4,5', '5,6']
```

The above list comprehension is comparable to:

```
result = []
for key in data:
    result.append(','.join(str(k) for k in key))
```